# Using an annotated class in BeanIO instead of an XML for mapping

Tags: java, spring, bean-io, spring-io

I'm following this simple tutorial http://beanio.org/
Toward the end says you can use an annotated class instead of an XML file. I did that and in my `factory.load()` I pass the value with the name of my annotated class. and I get am `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException`. I believe this is caused because its expecting an XML file.

What method I need to use to pass my annotated class instead of an XML?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to use a mapping class  instead of an XML you only have to add the following code

```
StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder("") // Your file
    .format("delimited")
    .parser(new DelimitedParserBuilder(',')) // Sign to  use as a delimiter
    .addRecord(Yourclass.class); // class to be mapped 

factory.define(builder);
```

This way an XML file is not need it at all.

Source:
http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#BuilderApiAndAnnotations